# Subprocess head versus DictReader to get header data (quickest way to pull file header info)

Tags: python, csv, subprocess

I am interested in the quickest way to pull column header data from a file for later use. Below I tried two different methods: Subprocess/head and DictReader. The results were multiple magnitudes different.

```
import subprocess
from csv import DictReader

def head_test():
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(['head','-n','1','file_data.txt'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for row in pipe.stdout:
        fields = row.strip().split('\t')

def dictreader_test():
    with open('file_data.txt') as f:
        f_info = DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
        fields = f_info.fieldnames

def fopen_test():
    with open('file_data.txt') as f:
        fields = next(f).strip().split('\t')

def rstrip_test():
    with open('file_data.txt') as f:
        fields = next(f).rstrip().split('\t')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit('head_test()', setup='from __main__ import head_test', number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit('dictreader_test()', setup='from __main__ import dictreader_test', number=100000))
    print(timeit.timeit('fopen_test()', setup='from __main__ import fopen_test', number=100000))
    print(timeit.timeit('rstrip_test()', setup='from __main__ import rstrip_test', number=100000))
```

Results:

```
34.6136500835
0.195073127747
```

Additional Results with last 3 tests bumped up to 100k:

```
1.85791897774
0.983640909195
0.973639011383
```

Even when the entire for loop in head_test is commented out it only accounts for about 20% of the time.

Two questions:
- Is there an even quick way to obtain column header data?
- What account for the major performance difference between these two methods?

Update: Added in additional tests from response suggestions

Comment: It's generally not worth creating a new process unless you're going to do a non-trivial amount of work. Especially on Windows; Unixes are generally better, and Linux especially so… but even on linux, it takes longer than just making a couple of function calls in the Python interpreter.

Comment: On the other hand… if you're only doing a trivial amount of work, the performance costs probably don't matter anyway. Is the wasted 3.4ms really going to make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be slightly quicker than `DictReader`:

```
fields = next(open('file_data.txt')).strip().split('\t')
```

This works because file objects (as returned by `open()`) are iterables that yield lines from the file, so `next(open('file_data.txt'))` will return the first line of the file.

The major difference in performance between `DictReader` and `Popen` is the overhead required to call a separate program to read the file and pass the results through a pipe to your Python program.

Comment: You probably want `with open('file_data.txt') as f: fields = next(f).strip().split('\t')`

Comment: or `with open('csv.txt', 'rb') as f: names = f.readline().rstrip().split('\t')` (to be able to pass `f` to `csv.reader()`)

Comment: Will post updated performance info in a min. I don't need to the file object afterwards, so the readline() format is not necessary, although rstrip() cuts off .01 seconds for every 100k iterations

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` actually launches an external program. On Unices that means forking the process and overwriting the child with the other executable. That is a lot of overhead over just reading through a file.

`DictReader` only has to read the first line of the file, which `head` has to do in addition to the process creation.

Comment: forks are optimized but if it just too read a file why not use python?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to say?

Comment: So you don't think it is responsible for the differences the OP is measuring?

Comment: I just just commented on the fork/copy parent/rewrite child part, however you are right reding the file in a separate process is indeed slower